# How to choose a specific thumbnail photo on like button

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I have a webpage i keep adding a like button app to but whenever i click like i get some random member phot of a lady on facebook representing my page.  this is frustrating.

I find all this html script and i cant seem to put it together properly so will you just please give me a simple paste ready like button formula with a set specific thumbnail photo that I can choose to represent my own page?

Answer (score 0):

Use the open graph properties for your webpage defined here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: this is all confusing to me and my friends... I simply need a like button that puts no thumbnail or a set thumbnail image to facebook when i click like on my webpage.